# Separar regiões do código usando o Sublime Text 3

Tags: estilo-de-codificação, sublime-text-3

No **Visual Studio** existe um recurso chamado [Diretiva #Region](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/sd032a17.aspx) , um recurso que recolhe e oculta seções de código.

**Exemplo**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            #region MyRegion1 
            //My code Here
            #endregion MyRegion1

            #region MyRegion2
            //My code Here
            #endregion MyRegion2

            #region MyRegion3
            //My code Here
            #endregion MyRegion3
        }
```

**Resultado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Existe algum recurso semelhante para o Sublime Text 3 ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stringnome, o mesmo recurso está disponível no Sublime Text 3.

A diferença na utilização é que o sublime só identifica blocos de código com o # na frente se a linha que identifica o bloco (#bloco) estiver sem identação.

Testei aqui e funcionou!

Comment: kkkkk cara para falar verdade eu não tinha tentando não hueheue , mas eu vi também que existe um recurso chamado code folding mesmo assim obrigado.